# How to install Apache on plesk17 in server windows

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, webserver, plesk

I have Windows server and install plesk17 on that. I have custom CMS and that used `.httpaccess` .

But my web server is iis and not to run `.httpaccess`; I can't change server to Linux...

Is Apache Installed On plesk17 Windows?

My main problem is just not running the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms/index.php?/$1 [L]�
```

I would appreciate it if I guide you so that I can solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can help with converting your .htaccess file to a URLRewrite rule.  Please note that URL Rewrite is not part of default IIS install and must be downloaded.  Available here: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Next the commands to create your URL Rewrite rule for Default Website is as follows:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules" -name "." -value @{name='ConvertedRule';stopProcessing='True'}
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='ConvertedRule']/match" -name "url" -value "^(.*)$"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='ConvertedRule']/match" -name "ignoreCase" -value "False"

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='ConvertedRule']/conditions" -name "." -value @{input='{REQUEST_FILENAME}';matchType='IsFile';negate='True'}

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='ConvertedRule']/conditions" -name "." -value @{input='{REQUEST_FILENAME}';matchType='IsDirectory';negate='True'}
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='ConvertedRule']/action" -name "type" -value "Rewrite"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='ConvertedRule']/action" -name "url" -value "/cms/index.php?/{R:1}"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='ConvertedRule']/action" -name "appendQueryString" -value "False"
```

and will produce configuration that looks as follows:

```
<rule name="ConvertedRule" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/cms/index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```